# Second view controller has no data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have the delegate method I implement to pass data from **FirstViewController** to **SecondViewController**.

First, I created a **text Field** and **Button** in  FirstViewController. Second, I created a **label** to display the data in SecondViewController.

***How it should work:*** 
The user will press the button in `FirstViewController` and it will pass the data to the `secondViewController`.In addition,the user will be using a **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** to navigate to the second view controller, so there's no need to use the button to go to the second view controller.

***How I test the application***

1- **I run the application**. --> 2- **I type "Hello" in Text field** --> 3- **I press the button** --> 4- **I swipe to the second view controller to see the data** --> 5- **I don't see any data in the label ??**

First i created the delegate protocol

***FirstViewController.h***

```
@class FirstViewController;

@protocol FirstControllerDelegate

-(void) updateLabel:(NSString*)string

@end

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FirstViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField;
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
```

***FirstViewController.m***

```
@interface FirstViewController. ()
@end
@implementation ViewController1
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize TextField;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {

  ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
   vc2.stringfromTextfield1 = self.TextField.text;

}
```

***SecondViewController.h***

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController<FirstControllerDelegate> 
@end
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringfromTextfield1;
```

***SecondViewController.m***

```
@interface SecondViewController. ()
    @end
    @implementation SecondViewController

    -(void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];

     self.label.text = self.stringfromTextfield1;

    }
```

**I appreciate your time and effort to help me out**

Comment: How do you show the second view controller, and where? I'm wondering if you are not creating a whole new `ViewController2` object.

Comment: I'm using tab bar and a swipe to navigate between these view controllers @Larme

Comment: then **do not** create view controllers on your own as you currently do. @Larme is 100% correct.

Comment: @luk2302  any suggestions how to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Singleton` class for this, or you can use `extern NSString` for move the string value one to second View Controller.

in first view controller.

```
extern NSString *MyStr;
```

in the `@interface`  define it.

```
@interface{
NSString *MyStr;
}
```

In the `@Implementation`  assign the value what you want.

and the second view controller just `#import` the first view and use,

`MyStr`  As a variable and its having the value also from first view controller.
This thing worked for me.

Comment: Is there any example or if you can answer this question with more information and code

Comment: Yes, Sure. @AssamAl-Zookery

Comment: it work in first view controller, but when i tried to use Mystr in my second view controller it didn't work Error : Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_Mystr", referenced from:

Comment: You import the first view in the second view controller.

Comment: I already import first view controller in second view controller but i still get the same error: error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) ..  would you please try to do it and if it works fine. would you please share more could so i could have better understanding what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you define String in the @interface of first view controller.

Comment: yes i did in the @interface of first view controller

Answer (score 1):

Or simply add an AppDelegate property to store the variable in both ViewControllers:

```
AppDelegate *appDel=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDel.variable=@"text";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save data in App delegate and access it across view controllers in your application.You have to create a shared instance of app delegate.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

**like this**

Suppose you declare a `NSString object *str`then you can access it in any view controller by `appDelegate.str`